# Code to print ticket

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am modifying my friend's railway reservation project, which is in vb.net. I am new to vb.net. There is one page **railwayreservation.aspx** which registers passengers. After clicking on register button, data is added in database file from the vb page.

I want to output this data on a simple html file. I have created new html file. After data  is added to database, how can I show data it in the html file? There are many data variable dim name , date ,etc on aspx.vb page.

Answer (score 2):

You can add text dynamically to the .aspx file from the associated aspx.vb file. In the html, add something like a `div` with an `id` where you'd like the reservation to appear:

```
<div id="reservationDiv"></div>
```

Inside the .aspx.vb, you can have something like this to update the aspx file:

```
reservationDiv.InnerHtml = Name & "<br>" ...
```

That will cause the text to magically be inserted inside the div (or other container) with an id of "reservationDiv".

(There are several other ways to accomplish this, too.)